# Lightsquid in Docker: resource mapping recommendations

Tags: linux, security, docker, squid

Now I'm trying to have some practice with docker and working on lightsquid containerization.
There is a practical task of setting up several Squid servers for different purposes so I realize that there will be a need to have different lightsquid containers.
I'd like to create as more common container as I can and my proposed solution here is:

- use lightsquid container only as interpreter of input data to output data;
- map one part of input data (configs) to docker host and use local git to maintain it;
- another part of input data (squid logs) will be generated by respective squid container;
- output data (lightsquid reports) will be mapped to respective docker host directory (and backuped/archived).

I [attached a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eeLr.jpg) to make more sense on this question.

So wouldn't you like to share your opinion about this scheme: is there any concerns or it is a standard way of containerization?

Each answer will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks OK so far. You might consider if it makes sense to map all your files below one root like `/srv/squid-container/etc`, `/srv/squid-container/log` etc. Because if you maintain a system as proposed, you are interleaving the regular system files with docker-related files which you will have to remember (or document e.g. with the picture) more thoroughly to not foreget parts if you are e.g. doing a migration or "uninstalling" the container.

Comment: @linux-fan Thanks a lot!